# Getting error : make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.31-20-generic/build: No such file or directory on Ubuntu 9.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make

When trying to install my WiFi card's driver on Ubuntu 9.1, I run the `make` command and get the following error:

```
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.31-20-generic/build: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: 9.10 reached end of life almost a year ago and is no longer supported, so you aren't getting security fixes.  You should upgrade immediately.

Answer (score 2):

This site gives a better solution/copy-paste code line to get the proper headers:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-kernel-headers-package/

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` Try this. If it wont work, comment and we'll figure out the package. (I hope you installed `build-essential` package.)

Comment: thanks for replying but that didn't work , can you advice some other package

Comment: You are missing the kernel headers. That is for SURE. Type `uname -a` in your terminal. You will see a message and you can check your kernel what are you using AT THE MINUTE. If you see that 2.6.31-20, then you need this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/linux-headers-2.6.31-20 . linux-headers-generic gets the latest headers, so if you are using some older kernel, you wont get its headers. *phew* So just use that link. :)